# How to stop jest running test constants folder

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, babel-jest

I am testing a React-Redux JS app with Jest, but I am having trouble stopping jest running my constants folder. I am using my constants folder to store various snapshots of the state and for mocking api responses as they can be quite large and I do not want them inline, and I may want to reuse in the future.

My folder structure is similar to below, where `testStates` is my constants folder:

 `|- __tests__
   |- some tests
   |- testStates
     |- state_errors
     |- state_some_errors
 |- app`

I have tried using the `package.json` to ignore module paths as the Jest documentation suggests [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string). However, as the documentation also says, I now cannot `import`/`require` these constants into my test suites.

Is there a way to exclude folders inside the test folder from being run, but also allow for importing in test suites?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running test constants folder". In which way does Jest "run" your constants folder?

Comment: jest thinks the constants folder, which contains `js` files, has test suites and then tries to run them with other tests. Which fails because either there are no tests in the files or I am exporting from that while which it doesn't like.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why your constants folder should be handled different than usual source code files. Jest wouldn't run your component code, will it?

Comment: No it does not run the actual component code. I wish to have my tests constants (example state/api response) inside of the `__tests__` folder which is why it tries to run it I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I use `modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["directoryNameToIgnore"]` to ignore files when I'm working with jest in my react native project.

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": ["./path/jestSetupFile.js"],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": ["./__tests__/constants-test.js"]
}
```

Jest docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring).

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer but I don't have the requisite reputation to post a comment. I have previously used a `__mock__` folder to separately store these files adjacent to the `__test__` folder and imported content from there. It allows for separating concerns for the files as you asked for, does not execute the tests.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will test this when I get an opportunity